# how to check filter length of field in a join query?

Tags: mysql, sql

currently my query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM suppliers s 
INNER JOIN supplier_addresses a 
ON s.id = a.supplier_id
```

in `supplier_addresses` there is a field that called `address` and I want to filter the result of the query above with only the addresses that have char length longer than 10?

i tried to add `where LEN(a.address) > 10` to the query above but dosent work..

Comment: Try `CHAR_LENGTH(a.address) > 10`

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't work" really means.  The logic is pretty obvious, so more explanation is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM suppliers s 
INNER JOIN supplier_addresses a 
ON s.id = a.supplier_id
WHERE char_length(a.address) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM suppliers s
INNER JOIN supplier_addresses a
ON (s.supplier_id = a.supplier_id)
WHERE LENGTH(a.address)>10;
```

Comment: `LENGTH` counts bytes; `CHAR_LENGTH` counts characters.  The difference matters for non-English text.